# C++ Builder: Location of Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, c++builder, firemonkey

I'm developping a mobile application using C++ Builder. I wanted to change the Bitmap of a FireMonkey TImage using the function LoadFromFile():

```
MyImage->Bitmap->LoadFromFile("My Image location");
```

I added the pictures to the project but I can't find the location of my Bitmap files. Does it exist a function or a parameter to find the location of these files?

Comment: I worked with this [instruction](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/delphi-xe5--deploying-and-accessing-local-files-on-ios-and-android-43005)

Comment: `I added the pictures to the project`. How and where? They should not only be on your PC but contained in the apk on the Android device.

Comment: I right clicked on my project and clicked on Add... then selected my pictures. I can see them in my Project Manager with all the other files.

Comment: @KeremD I tried your solution but when I execute I have this message: "Load of Bitmap failed(/data/data/<my_package>/Picture.bmp)"

Comment: Check if the file exists with `FileExists`. If so try another bitmap.

Comment: @Dylan: You did not add the bitmaps to the project correctly.  You need to use the [Deployment Manager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Deployment_Manager), not the Project Manager. Put the bitmaps into the project's assets, and add the `System.StartupCopy` unit to your `uses` clause. Then you can access the asset files at runtime using `TPath` to find the correct folder. See [Deploying and accessing local files on iOS and Android](http://community.embarcadero.com/article/articles-tutorials/151-ui/927-deploying-and-accessing-local-files-on-ios-and-android)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried with the Deployment Manager and the System.StartupCopy but it seems that the format of my bitmap is the problem. With the Project Manager (or Deployment) and a PNG image, it works.

Comment: @Dylan you still need to use the Deployment Manager to do things *correctly*. As for the BMP issue, that is [documented behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.LoadFromFile): "*For a list of formats supported by each platform, see [TBitmapCodecManager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmapCodecManager#Supported_Image_Formats).*" BMP is supported only on Windows and OSX, JPG and PNG are the only formats supported on *all* platforms.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your answer! I'll do it with the Deployment Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why my Picture loading failed. I tried to use a .bmp file which is only supported  on Windows and OSX. I worked with the instruction given by Kerem D [here](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/delphi-xe5--deploying-and-accessing-local-files-on-ios-and-android-43005). I converted my picture to a PNG format and now it worked. Thank you all for your answers!